# How do I increase my Virtual Server's clock speed?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to buy a faster clock speed with Azure using their web interface within my Virtual Machine?

Comment: Hosting is off-topic here.  Asking about their web interface would be on-topic.

Comment: @jonsca I'm asking how to use their web interface to increase clock speed. I shouldn't need to log into the VPS at any point to increase it.

Comment: I have tried to clarify the question with that information, feel free to make any further adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change clock speed of Azure virtual machine as Hyper-V underneath this machine just does not have such functionality. All you can do - change quantity of logical processors and set physical processor`s priority for your virtual machine.